# ASP.NET :: Can a textbox control's onblur/lostFocus event trigger a server-side event?

Tags: asp.net, events, server-side, onblur, lostfocus

I am trying to attach a server-side event to lookup the city/state for the user-entered zipcode in a field like the one below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextZipcode" runat="server" CssClass="inputtext" Columns="10" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

Since there is no lost focus event to capture, has anyone had any luck getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, why not? Just attach a JavaScript handler and have it invoke an AJAX action.